# How to fix: ERR Protocol error: expected '$', got ' '

Tags: python-3.x, windows, powershell, redis, cat

I am using Redis-3.2.1, Python-3.6, Powershell-v1.0, and Windows 7. I am attempting to perform a mass-insertion into Redis. I've created a mass-insertion file with the RESP protocol in Python 3.6. When I execute "cat redis_data.txt | redis-cli --pipe" in Powershell, the following error occurs:

```
PS C:\Users\shiner> cat redis_data.txt | redis-cli --pipe
ERR Protocol error: expected '$', got ' '
All data transferred. Waiting for the last reply...
No replies for 30 seconds: exiting.
errors: 2, replies: 1
```

(I am new to powershell so please keep that in mind)

Here is my python code:

```
import redis
r = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)

import sys

def gen_redis_proto(*args):
    proto = ""
    proto += "*"+str(args.__len__())+"\r\n"
    for arg in args:
        proto += "$"+str(str(arg).__len__())+"\r\n"
        proto += str(arg)+"\r\n"
    return proto

def generate_data_file():
    f = open('redis_data.txt', 'w')
    [f.write(gen_redis_proto("SET", "KEY{0}".format(x), 
                         "VALUE{0}".format(x)))
    for x in range(0, 400)]

generate_data_file()
```

A sample of the text file looks like:

"*3$3SET$4KEY0$6VALUE0*3$3SET$4KEY1$6VALUE1*3$3SET$4KEY2$6VALUE2*3$3SET$4KEY3$6VALUE3*3$3SET$4KEY4$6VALUE4*3$3SET$4KEY5$6VALUE5*3$3SET$4KEY6$6VALUE6*3$3SET$4KEY7$6VALUE7*3$3SET$4KEY8$6VALUE8*3$3SET$4KEY9$6VALUE9*3$3SET$5KEY10$7VALUE10*3$3SET$5KEY11$7VALUE11*3$3SET$5KEY12$7VALUE12*3$3SET$5KEY13$7VALUE13*3$3SET$5KEY14$7VALUE14...Value399'

'Value399' is the last 8 characters in text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems an issue with your file format. Please create an input file with below format:

```
SET Key0 Value0 
SET Key1 Value1 
...
SET KeyN ValueN
```

Above PowerShell command is working fine for me.
Output :

```
PS C:\> cat redis_data.txt | redis-cli  --pipe
All data transferred. Waiting for the last reply...
Last reply received from server.
errors: 0, replies: 2
```

Comment: Your suggestion works for me too. Next step is to write a function to write multiple keys in that format with python. I got the python code I tried above from http://blog.csprabala.com/2016/07/23/Redis-Mass-Insert-Function-In-Python/. Perhaps it was intended for a different version of Redis.